# Can't get onclick event to appear in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, onclick

I have a goal in GA, and a matching onclick event on a button as follows...

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://amzn.to/2xr9Kgx" class="btn_bmi blue white" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'BuyNow', 'click');">Buy Now</a>
```

When I click the link I should see the event fire in GA > REAL TIME > Events. However, nothing appears.

I don't get any console errors so the onclick event seems fine.

I thought maybe the "target="_blank"" was not allowing the JS to finish firing, but the onclick page remains in the browser so I don;t think that's the issue. Just in case, tho, I tested with just a regular link going to another page in the site. Still no event in GA.

If you want to see a sample page, hit this...

```
http://www.bigmouthinc.com/products/giant-donut-pool-float/
```

The onclick event is attached to the blue "Buy Now" button.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are using the gtag.js implementation of Google Analytics to track pageviews but the analytics.js implementation of event tracking.

You should change to using one of

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

For both the page and event tracking.